# connecting iPad to a TV

Tags: tv, ipad

I have an iPad and I am interested in buying a TV for it, so I can watch online videos with the iPad providing the input. I guess my questions are the following:

1. What type of connection should I make sure the TV has? Maybe it is better/a must to get a computer screen?
2. Is there anything like a remote control that I can use for the iPad and buy at the Apple Store?
3. Is there anything else I need to know about this setup? Maybe it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a TV with HDMI inputs and the [Apple HDMI AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A). You won't need a remote as the iPad will be your controller.

You could also get an [Apple TV](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipod/family/apple_tv) and stream the videos wirelessly.

You should be aware that many of the more-desirable features (like screen mirroring for apps that don't support TV outputs) won't work on an original iPad; you'll have a better experience if you have an iPad 2 or newer.